# Calculate 30 days forward, excluding weekends and holidays

Tags: calculated-column, date

One user wants to have a column, which will be a Date 30 days forward, but when if it falls on a weekend or holiday, it has to be after that. For example, today is 11/25, so after 30 days, it will be 12/25, so it should be 12/27. In the column. I know the function `WORKDAY` exists, but it counts only just workdays, not every day...

I try to use order of holiday days with function `WEEKDAY` and `IF`, but the function is very very long. In MS Excel, there can I use `COUNTIF`, but in SP I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. I'm from Czech Republic, so there is our holiday's and for easterday now it calculates to year 2022.

```
=if(or(text(date+30,"d.m.")="1.1.",text(date+30,"d.m.yyyy")="17.4.2017",text(date+30,"d.m.yyyy")="2.4.2018",text(date+30,"d.m.yyyy")="22.4.2019",text(date+30,"d.m.yyyy")="13.4.2020",text(date+30,"d.m.yyyy")="5.4.2021",text(date+30,"d.m.yyyy")="18.4.2022",text(date+30,"d.m.")="1.5.",text(date+30,"d.m.")="8.5.",text(date+30,"d.m.")="6.7.",text(date+30,"d.m.")="28.9.",text(date+30,"d.m.")="28.10.",text(date+30,"d.m.")="17.11.",text(date+30,"d.m.")="26.12."),if(weekday(date+31,2)=6,date+33,if(weekday(date+31,2)=7,date+32,date+31)),if(or(text(date+30,"d.m.")="5.7.",text(date+30,"d.m.")="25.12."),if(weekday(date+32,2)=6,date+34,if(weekday(date+32,2)=7,date+33,date+32)),if(text(date+30,"d.m.")="24.12.",if(weekday(date+33,2)=6,date+35,if(weekday(date+33,2)=7,date+34,date+33)),if(or(text(date+30,"d.m.yyyy")="14.4.2017",text(date+30,"d.m.yyyy")="30.3.2018",text(date+30,"d.m.yyyy")="19.4.2019",text(date+30,"d.m.yyyy")="10.4.2020",text(date+30,"d.m.yyyy")="2.4.2020",text(date+30,"d.m.yyyy")="15.4.2022"),date+34,if(weekday(date+30,2)=6,date+32,if(weekday(date+30,2)=7,date+31,date+30))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but there may be people out there still using SharePoint 2013 Foundation with SP workflow 2010 like me, hope this workaround helps. It uses 2 lists and workflows to create a loop until it finds the date that does not fall on weekend or holiday. The advantage is that user can easily maintain their holidays without using hard coded calculated column.

> Scenario: Find the next working day by excluding weekends
>   & holidays.

---

1. Create 2 lists. One is the main list and the other for checking holidays.

**Main list:**

- CurrentDateTime (Date & Time) - format Date Only
- NextReminderDate (Date & Time) - format Date Only
- Workflow (Choice) - with 3 options – 1,2,3, default value 1
- DaysToSkip (Number) – default 0 and no decimal point
- IsWeekend (Calculated) – Formula=

  IF(OR(WEEKDAY(CalcNextDay)=1,WEEKDAY(CalcNextDay)=7),"Yes","No")
  Value will be “Yes” if CalcNextDay falls on weekend
- CalcNextDay (Calculated) – Formula=

  CurrentDateTime+DaysToSkip

[image]

**Holiday list:**

- Create a Date & Time column

[image]

---

2. Create 2 separate workflows in SP Designer for main list. Second workflow will be triggered to restart first workflow from top.

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

3. Workflow# 1 contains an IF or ELSE condition:

   - The first condition will be triggered when item is created, since default value is 1.
   - Add 1 day to current DaysToSkip (originally 0).
   - Trigger Workflow# 2 to check if CalcNextDay falls on weekend or holiday.

---

4. Workflow 2 contains 1 parallel block with 2 steps.

   - If CalcNextDay equals Holiday:Date

[image]

- Or if IsWeekend calculated value is “Yes”
- Workflow 1 will be triggered again to add 1 day to skip.
- This process repeats until both conditions are no longer met, and the next step “Working” is triggered to call first workflow, set NextReminderDate to CalcNextDay and stop the workflows.

---

5. Example:

[image][image]